# Specify target Vega version for vega-lite and vega-embed?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I am (successfully) using vega-lite@2 and vega-embed@3 to display a simple bar chart. However, I get the following error in the console:

```
The compiled spec uses Vega v3, but current version is 4.0.0.
```

Is there a way I can instruct vega-lite to compile to vega@4? Should I just ignore this warning?

Here's a sandboxed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/rlvjw5wonm

Note that I am importing vega-embed as a module. I wasn't able to find many examples using vega* this way, so it's possible I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning, not an error. I will update Vega-Embed as soon as the Typescript team resolves an issue that is blocking us right now.